# Python - Get build-id from an ELF file

Tags: python, build, elf

I'm trying to extract the build-id from and ELF file (Linux kernel module).
Right now it's using:

```
subprocess.check_output(['eu-readelf', '-n', filename]).split()[-1]
```

I was wondering is there's a more pythony way to achieve the same result?

Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `eu-readelf` command from python, as you have done, is the most elegant and readable approach. Since python stresses readability, I'd say this is the most Pythonic approach.